# tinymce-react js not showing UI and plugings just simple textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce

I install tinymce-react but I could not see UI for tinymce-react just simple textarea as you can see in the image, So can you help me to fix this that it can working normally like rich text editor

```
     import { Editor } from "@tinymce/tinymce-react";

     <Editor
            style={{ margin: "0px !important" }}
            apiKey="jwg59xe6oa4x0o733wyeew4t655r396pbt4vqgre3mseiyxt"
            initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
            init={{
              height: 500,
              menubar: false,
              plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount",
              ],
              toolbar:
                "undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor |" +
                "alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | " +
                "bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help",
            }}
          />
```

[image]